# How to create a datepicker in react js

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I tried different method to develop date picker in reactJS. I done with "react-datepicker" package and it return "Wed May 15 2019 12:54:33 GMT+0100" as a result but I need 12/12/2000 format

Comment: Any date picker library would allow you to select the date. If you need to format the data, you might need to pass some props according to the library or you can modify it urself as per ur requirement.

Comment: I couldn't get your points. Please share any example code

Answer (score 0):

try to format it as you want

```js
const pickerDate = new Date('Wed May 15 2019 12:54:33 GMT+0100')
const day = pickerDate.getDay() < 10 ?  '0' + pickerDate.getDay() : pickerDate.getDay()
const month = pickerDate.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' + (pickerDate.getMonth() + 1) : pickerDate.getMonth() + 1
const year = pickerDate.getFullYear()
const formatedDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`
```

you can also use third part libraries like `moment`